# RBF network normalization, standardization in MATLAB

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, rbf-network

First of all, is it good to do normalization and standardization for Radial basis neural network?

Does MATLAB do that automatically for RBF? I've read that MATLAB does normalization and standardization for Feedforward neural network, but I am not sure If it does for RBF too. I use *nntool* and I don't see if MATLAB does normalization or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range normalization (0,1) is necessary for RBF network.
MATLAB doesn't normalize RBF networks automatically (only feedforward network).

Comment: [Radial basis function networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network) are normalized on the interval {0,1} since they use positive norms to do so, n'est pas? Answer could use a bit more text to be more robust.

Comment: Is it actually mistake use {-1,1} normalization instead of 0,1? Gaussian function in RBF should makes numbers correct anyway.

Comment: If you think the normalization would be {-1,1}, then find a reference to that effect. I gave a reference for the {0,1} interval because that is what I found. I have no idea what it is used for. Maybe you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter which size of range you set until you set it for all atributes. I do calculation for it later. You posted link on wiki, but I dont see any mention about normalization on the interval {0,1}.

Comment: It is not stated explicitly. However, as $\rho>0$ and the normalization uses $\rho$ times the ratio of absolute values or their sums, then the interval is {0,1}.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451445.aspx  in the middle of article is example with negative values.

Comment: I cannot tell if they are doing the same things in both articles or not. It would be nice if they said what they are doing. But, they do not seem to be too forthcoming.